# how to adjust my javascript countdown to repeat over again after execution

Tags: javascript

With the following code I want to count down and after the timer has reached 00:00 it will change window location. All is working up until that point. My question is how do I make this process repeat again after the window location has changed? I will be using this for a chrome extension to run in the background.

```
var sec = 5; // set the seconds
var min = 10; // set the minutes

function countDown() {

    sec--;
    if (sec == -1) {
        sec = 59;
        min = min - 1;
    } else {
        min = min;
    }
    if (sec <= 9) {
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }
    time = (min <= 9 ? "0" + min : min) + " min and " + sec + " sec ";
    document.getElementById('theTime').innerHTML = time;
    SD = window.setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
    if (min == '00' && sec == '00') {
        sec = "00";
        window.clearTimeout(SD);
        window.location = 'http://mywebsite.com';
    }

}

window.addEventListener("load", countDown, false);
```

Comment: Can you clarify. Do you also control the site mywebsite.com

Comment: @jottos: what difference does that make? All the author wants to do is redirect to the site.

Comment: @jordan if you don't control the destination page then there is no way to set the timer again after changing the current window.location, if you do control the destination page then you write code to re-establish the timer or coordinate with an extension

Comment: @jottos: gotcha, but the author mentioned it was for a Chrome extension. Maybe your comment came in before the edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( min==0 && sec=='00' )
```

Your min is an integer and not a string ('00'). You are only displaying it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to inject the countdown code into the loaded page. I'm not sure how chrome extensions work, so I can't help you there.

An easier way to do this would be to put the target page in an `<iframe>` and then change the `src` attribute of that instead. You can make the iframe the size of the entire window so it looks normal. The only problem is that you would lose control over the address bar (it wouldn't change to whatever you set `src` to)

Comment: The <iframe> option is only likely to work if you are iframing your own page. Many sites now set the X-frame-options reply header to DENY or SAMEORIGIN which will prevent you from iframing that site.